# Why is the static variable in Base Class not accessible in Child Class?

Tags: java, inheritance, static

```
class BaseClass{
    static int count1=10;
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Invoking display method of Base Class");
    }
}

public class SingleInheritance01 extends BaseClass {
    int value=200;
    static int count2=10;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        SingleInheritance01 objDerivedClass=new SingleInheritance01();
        objDerivedClass.display();
    }
}

/*
The object created in Derived Class cannot reference static variables in Base Class as well as
```

Derived
    I can access it using ClassName -I am under the assumption that as static variables are common to instances of the class.
    */

Comment: This works just fine for me. Could you clarify what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Mureinik  --I cannot see objDerivedClass.count,i.e I cant get static variable in the base class using the object in the derived class

Comment: There's no `objDerviedClass.count`, only `objDerviedClass.count1`, which you can definitely access.

Comment: count1 itself -Not seeing it

Comment: package Test;

//Not Able to Access Static Members from Derived Class
class BaseClass {
    static int count1 = 10;

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Invoking display method of Base Class");
    }
}

public class SingleInheritance01 extends BaseClass {
    int value = 200;
    static int count2 = 10;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SingleInheritance01 objDerivedClass = new SingleInheritance01();
        objDerivedClass.display();
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

First off, static variables are not tied to instances. You should be accessing them using Class name. You could use the object to access it, but its not recommended. If the purpose of making `count1` `static` was to access it in a sub class, you can remove the `static` modifier.
Second, the visibility of `count1` is determined by the access modifier. Right now its `default`. Which means its visible only to classes in the same package. So my guess is that your `BaseClass` is in a different package than your subclass.

If you change it to `protected` or public you'll be able to access it in the sub class.

If you do want to keep it static, then you may do so but will have to change its access to protected or public

Comment: Object access is a warning. Is there any reason for doing that? I cannot recollect from the top of the method. Wonder why it is only a warning and not an error.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are by definition `not "instance variables"`. Their state is available to all instances of that Class.

They are termed as class variables and are generally used to hold resources shared across the instances of the class. Of course you would have to take into account threading issues in certain situations.

One use of a class variable (statics) is in an implementation of the `Singleton Design Pattern`.

You could access static variables of the base class in any of the classes in the same package (default package in your case since no packages are defined). This includes any of the derived classes within the package. If you want to make it available across packages, use the `"public"` modifier. To access a static variables, simply prefix the class name.

```
Ex: BaseClass.count1
```

Also note when using static variables, they are not inherited in derived classes.